# How to call a .cs method from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to call a .cs method from JavaScript function; how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some more detail about your situation.

Comment: Here's how http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=call+javascript+asp.net+function+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=8631cdd35a4d476d and notice that those are limited only to answers you already have on StackOverflow (according to Google about 50,200 results). Simply pick the one that works in your scenario (which by the way you haven't defined).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do post back to the server then catch this post back on Pageload event then execute the cs function.

check the following article:
[Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.all)

Answer (score 0):

You need to postback to the server by either submitting an HTML form or using JavaScript.  If you're not in a browser, it might be more of a challenge because I don't think the Windows Scripting Host includes anything that can call the web by default.  In which case you could use something like cURL instead.