# How to call server side class code method from javascript?

Tags: javascript, server-side

I want to know how to call .cs method from javascript file in asp.net

Comment: In your title you state you want to make a call **from the client** to the server. In the question body you talk about making  a call from server **to the client**. What do you want to do?

Comment: sorry i want to call .cs method from javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a .cs method from a JavaScript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486683/how-to-call-a-cs-method-from-a-javascript-function)

Comment: I recommend you learn to use google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Use either of the following,

```
     1. If your code is within aspx.cs create a static webmethod and call this webmethod using Page Method from javascript

     2. If your code is within a webservice, Call the webservice from javascript.
```

Hope this helps